# CakePHP URLs load view in a separate window

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm having a problem with my URLs in CakePHP. I have a controller named 'users' that has an index and a highscores action(action, method, function, whatever). When I go to mydomain.com/users, I get the index view loaded in my layout. Perfect. But, when I go to mydomain.com/users/ it loads the index in a new page, outside of the layout. It only shows the view. Also, when I go to mydomain.com/users/highscores, it loads the high scores in a new page, outside of the layout, just the view. I have mod_rewrite enabled. It does this on both my localhost and on a live test server. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Jason

Comment: I figured it out. My stylesheets were using relative positioning, so the pages were loading, just no css or js. Note to self...always view source.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My stylesheets were using relative positioning, so the pages were loading, just no css or js. Note to self...always view source.